# Understanding HDF5's slabs

Tags: c, hdf5

First of all, forgive my very basic question: I'm going through the tutorials and I've successfully written my first HDF5 dataset. Now, I'm moving to slabs, but I'm finding difficulties in doing this.

As far as I understand, I need to obtain a valid memory space, select a slab, and then write my data. But obviously I'm doing something wrong, since I get errors:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.14) thread 0:
  #000: H5Dio.c line 271 in H5Dwrite(): can't prepare for writing data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Write failed
  #001: H5Dio.c line 352 in H5D__pre_write(): can't write data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Write failed
  #002: H5Dio.c line 690 in H5D__write(): src and dest data spaces have different sizes
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Bad value
```

Obviously I'm trying to write data with wrong dimensions, but I don't know how to correct that. My goal is to create a 20x3 matrix, and set the *second* row to `{ 10, 20, 30 }`:

```
 0  0  0
10 20 30
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
```

Can you help me in understanding this issue? My buggy code is below!

Thanks!

```
#include "hdf5.h"

#define FILE "dset.h5"
#define DSET "/dset"

int main() {

  hid_t        file_id, dataset_id, dataspace_id, filespace, memspace;
  hsize_t      dims[2], offset[2], count[2];
  herr_t       status;

  unsigned int dset_data[3] = { 10, 20, 30 };

  /* Create a new file using default properties. */
  file_id = H5Fcreate(FILE, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

  /* Create the data space for the dataset. */
  dims[0] = 20; /* ROWS */
  dims[1] = 3;    /* COLS */
  dataspace_id = H5Screate_simple(2, dims, NULL);

  /* Create the dataset. */
  dataset_id = H5Dcreate2(file_id, DSET, H5T_STD_I32BE, dataspace_id,
                          H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

  /* Get the memory space */
  memspace = H5Dget_space (dataset_id);

  offset[0] = 1; /* ROWS */
  offset[1] = 0; /* COLS */

  count[0]  = 1; /* ROWS */
  count[1]  = 3; /* COLS */

  /* Select the slab */
  status = H5Sselect_hyperslab(memspace, H5S_SELECT_SET,
                               offset, NULL, count, NULL);

  /* Write the dataset. */
  status = H5Dwrite(dataset_id, H5T_NATIVE_INT,
                    memspace, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT,
                    dset_data);

  /* End access to the dataset and release resources used by it. */
  status = H5Dclose(dataset_id);

  /* Terminate access to the data space. */
  status = H5Sclose(dataspace_id);

  /* Close the file. */
  status = H5Fclose(file_id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your data is contiguous *in memory* (`memspace`) but it's an hyperslab in *the file's space* (`dataspace_id`). So you need to do your selection on `dataset_id`, not `memspace`.

And you need to size `memspace` to contain just enough space for your row. Here I would just create a simple 1D dataspace of 3 elements. Like this the size of the hyperslab (3 elements) and the size in memory will match.

Comment: Hello @Simon, I've tried to add a new variable for the data size `newsize[1] = { 3 }`, adding the resizing of memspace `status = H5Dextend (memspace, newsize);` right after `memspace = H5Dget_space (dataset_id);`, and finally the slab selection is on the data set `status = H5Sselect_hyperslab(dataset_id, H5S_SELECT_SET, offset, NULL, count, NULL);`. But I get two errors: `H5Ddeprec.c line 315 in H5Dextend(): not a dataset`, and `H5Shyper.c line 6593 in H5Sselect_hyperslab(): not a data space`. I am missing something here...  full code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ef0386340eefb4ef5b23

Comment: Don't try to *get* the memory space, *create* it with `H5Screate_simple `.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, tweaking the original source code and leaving the original "memspace = H5Dget_space (dataset_id);" in as-is, I got it to work fine a Linux system.

```
#include <hdf5/serial/hdf5.h>

#define FILE "dset.h5"
#define DSET "/dset"

int main() {

  hid_t        file_id, dataset_id, dataspace_id, memspace;
  // hid_t filespace;
  hsize_t      dims[2], offset[2], count[2];
  herr_t       status;

  unsigned int dset_data[3] = { 10, 20, 30 };

  /* Create a new file using default properties. */
  file_id = H5Fcreate(FILE, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

  /* Create the data space for the dataset. */
  dims[0] = 20; /* ROWS */
  dims[1] = 3;    /* COLS */
  dataspace_id = H5Screate_simple(2, dims, NULL);

  /* Create the dataset. */
  dataset_id = H5Dcreate(file_id, DSET, H5T_STD_I32BE, dataspace_id,
                          H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

  /* Get the memory space */
  memspace = H5Dget_space (dataset_id);

  offset[0] = 1; /* ROWS */
  offset[1] = 0; /* COLS */

  count[0]  = 1; /* ROWS */
  count[1]  = 3; /* COLS */

  /* Select the slab */
  status = H5Sselect_hyperslab(dataspace_id, H5S_SELECT_SET,
                               offset, NULL, count, NULL);
  if(status < 0)
    return status;
    
  /* Write the dataset. */
  status = H5Dwrite(dataset_id, H5T_NATIVE_INT,
                    memspace, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT,
                    dset_data);
  if(status < 0)
    return status;

  /* End access to the dataset and release resources used by it. */
  status = H5Dclose(dataset_id);
  if(status < 0)
    return status;

  /* Terminate access to the data space. */
  status = H5Sclose(dataspace_id);
  if(status < 0)
    return status;

  /* Close the file. */
  status = H5Fclose(file_id);
  return status;
}
```